# GitHub Actions token permissions to change repository settings

Tags: github-actions

I'm in github Enterprise trying below action which sets certain team to a repository whenever some action is done on it (in this case a push on master).

```
name: Repo-Creation-Action
run-name: Repository Creation [${{ github.event.repository.name }}]
on: [push]
jobs:
  Set-Repository-Permissions:
    if: ${{ !contains(github.ref, 'refs/heads/master/') }}   
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Changing repository permissions (API)
        run: |
          $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
          $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
          $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}")
          $headers.Add("User-Agent", "DSC-EF-SelfHostedRunner")
          $body = '{"permission": "push"}'
          Invoke-RestMethod 'https://mygitenterprise.com/api/v3/orgs/${{ github.repository_owner }}/teams/testgroup/repos/${{ github.repository }}' -Method 'PUT' -Headers $headers -Body $body
```

The problem I have is that if I use the secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN, it gives me a NotFound error.

```
0s
Current runner version: '2.299.2'
Runner name: 'Server-Runner'
Runner group name: 'Testing-Runners'
Machine name: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
  Actions: write
  Checks: write
  Contents: write
  Deployments: write
  Discussions: write
  Issues: write
  Metadata: read
  Packages: write
  Pages: write
  PullRequests: write
  RepositoryProjects: write
  SecurityEvents: write
  Statuses: write
Secret source: Actions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
2s
Run $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
  
Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.8/rest/refe
rence/teams/#add-or-update-team-repository-permissions"}
At D:\_work\_temp\d57a90c6-447c-401f-b9ca-ef77f8f4120b.ps1:7 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod 'https://xxxxxx/api/v3/orgs/ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have tried to use my own token (hardcoded) and it works well...

Also I have tried to use the secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN with a very simple GET request and it worked fine...

Seeing all this it looks like the automatically generated token is working on basic calls but is not able to perform the initial API call... And that initial call is working ok if my token is used.

Any clues on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you attempt to access is not in the scope for the `GITHUB_TOKEN` because that token is "limited to the repository that contains your workflow" (see["About `GITHUB_TOKEN`" docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token)) and teams are outside that scope - same as any other administative actions within a repository.

Using a Personal Access Token, as you have, or a GitHub App, are the only options here.